# Virtual coordinate system

Tags: c, graphics, uvw

I have some questions about ray tracing:

How can I calculate w,v,u unit vectors according to world coordinate system ?

```
                      |----------------------|
    up vector         |                      |
      ^               |                      |
      |               |          .           |
      |               |                      |
      .               |       gaze point     |
                      |                      |
  eye origin          |                      |
                      |----------------------|
                               screen
```

How can I generate a perspective ray for ( i,j) ?

```
                      |----------------------|
    up vector         |                      |
      ^               |                      |
      |               |          .           |
      |               |                      |
      .               |       (i,j)          |
                      |                      |
  eye origin          |                      |
                      |----------------------|
                               screen
```

Comment: As per your convention, what do w,u and v mean?

Comment: w,u,v means virtual coordinate systems

Comment: What is a virtual coordinate system?